# How can I take the original image size in reactnavie conditional rendering?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

The PostList function is a component inside FlatList.

When I have an item.Image, I want the Image to occupy that size with conditional rendering and push item.content

But with my code, it doesn't take up as wide as the Image due to item.content. like this Screenshot  the green one is Image width

[image]

How can I push the item.content when the item.Image is present while the Image takes up its normal width?

this is my code

```
        const PostList = ({item}: Props) => {


          return (
            <>
              <View style={styles.main}>
                <View style={styles.min}>
                  <View style={styles.middlecon}>
                    <Text style={styles.content} numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode="tail">
                      {item.content}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </View>

                {item.Image && (
                  <View style={styles.rightcon}>
                    <Image style={styles.Image} />
                  </View>
                )}
              </View>
            </>
          );
        };

        const styles = StyleSheet.create({
          main: {
            borderBottomWidth: 0.3,
            borderColor: '#b0b4b8',
            paddingBottom: 30,
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
          },

          min: {},

          middlecon: {},

          content: {},

          rightcon: {
            backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
          },

          Image: {
            width: 100,
            height: 30,
            backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
            
          },
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to also pass the image's source to the `Image` component.
Like so:

```
<Image
  style={styles.tinyLogo}
  source={require('@expo/snack-static/react-native-logo.png')}
/>
```

Also, if you don't have the image stored locally and you instead of its uri, you can do the following:

```
<Image
  style={styles.tinyLogo}
  source={{
    uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png',
  }}
/>
```

Source: https://reactnative.dev/docs/image

Also, to make sure that the image stays within the height and width you've set in your styles, add `resizeMode: contain` as another prop to the `Image` component.

Comment: i've tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Could you be more specific? What exactly have you tried?

Comment: i'v tried  " resizeMode: contain " and   source={{
    uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png',
  }}
but it  is same

Comment: Make sure your uri has https at the front, try using this exactly "https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png"

Comment: Also, check the value of ```item.Image```, it could be ```null``` or ```undefined``` and cause your ```Image``` component to not render.

Comment: What I'm trying to do now is not an image shape. It is whether the image occupies according to its size or not.  And even if I put the image uri properly, the image does not occupy the size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244161/discussion-between-man517-and-user15322469).